# JEST config testing node_module even if its disabled?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, jestjs

I am adding tests to existing codebase with Jest. This is the error I am getting

```
   Jest encountered an unexpected token
    This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.

    By default, if Jest sees a Babel config, it will use that to transform your files, ignoring "node_modules".

    Here's what you can do:
     • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
     • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
     • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

    You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html

    Details:

    /home/me/app/node_modules/register-service-worker/index.js:32
    export function register (swUrl, hooks) {
    ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
```

I do not understand how to configure the `transformIgnorePatterns` properly?
But my `jest.config.js` is setup to ignore `node_modules` ?
Looking into the [react example](https://jestjs.io/docs/tutorial-react-native#transformignorepatterns-customization) but can not really make sense how it translates to my stuff...? I'm in VueJS project, no typescript is used.

```
module.exports = {
  preset: "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest/presets/typescript-and-babel",
  moduleNameMapper: {
    "^@/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/$1",
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: ["/node_modules/"],
  // setupFiles: [
  //   "./tests/unit/setup.ts",
  // ],
};
```

Comment: My advice, create a [mock](https://jestjs.io/docs/manual-mocks#mocking-node-modules) for `register-service-worker`. You shouldn't really be testing 3rd party code anyway

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/1879#issuecomment-409872897)

Comment: @Phil - the OP isn't trying to test third party code, they are wondering why `node_modules` isn't being ignore. Creating a mock for that service worker will just result in something else in `node_modules` trying to be transpiled.

Comment: @Adam what I mean is that 3rd party code is being included in the test which is out of your control. IMO, collaborators should be controlled

Comment: @Adam The linked suggestions did unfortunately not help. Same error. I will try to mock it as I need to learn that anyways... But if someone knows how to block Jest from  looking into `node_modules` in my case please let me know. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems extending `jest.config.js` solved the error above.

```
  "transform": {
    ".*\\.(vue)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/vue-jest",
    "^.+\\.js$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest"
  },
```

I now have a different error, but this is more Vue specific now.